# How to make HTTP POST request call from Dojo version 1.7 or below?

Tags: http, post, get, dojo, dojo-1.7

I am new to dojo and using version 1.7.Making service call from dojo now i need to change the request method from GET to POST. For GET request currently i am using **dojo/io/script**, for POST should use **dojo/request/script** suggested by 
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/io/script.html . But **dojo/request/script** introtuced in dojo 1.8. Is there any other method to call POST types or need to go with dojo 1.8? Help me to resolve this ,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's preferable not to use `dojo/io/script` , and this last is deprecated in 1.8 version as per as listed in [documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/script.html#dojo-request-script) .

If You want to call a specific script file in order to embed it into a page or an app , use dojo/request/script ,

So it's better to migrate to 1.8

Otherwise if you want to call an endpoint that return data , html , or some results ,
just use only the [`dojo/request`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request.html#dojo-request)

```
require(["dojo/request"], function(request){
    request.post(url, {data:data, method: 'POST', handleAs: 'json'}).then(
        function(response){
            //success
        },
        function(error){
            //error
        }
    );
});
```